# How to find all computers running Windows 10 with Active Directory DirectorySearcher?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to set a filter for a `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` that locates all computers running Windows 10 within a domain. What is the syntax for a filter that combines two criteria? I tried with

```
$Searcher   = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]$LDAPProviderPath)
$SearchRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($LDAPProviderPath, "...", "...")

$Searcher.SearchRoot = $SearchRoot

$Searcher.filter="(&(objectCategory=computer)(OperatingSystem=Windows 10))"
```

How to correctly set the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
"(&(objectCategory=computer) (operatingSystem=*Windows 10*))"
```

as LDAP filter.